# how to create Update in three tier archirtecture

Tags: asp.net, .net, 3-tier

I am creating an ASP.NET project in 3 tier architecture. I want to edit a person details. Can i implement it in FormView (In EditItemTemplate) or need to create separate classes for business logic and data access. Which is the better Way?

Comment: What do you consider to be the 3rd tier?

Answer (score 0):

It is Depend on your requirement but best practice is "To create separate classes for business logic and data access." it stand for tree tier

Comment: thans for your valuable feedback  :)